# Xcode 15 Strange behaviour with refreshable list - progress indicator remains visible

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I'm having a problem with a refreshable list view in my App. This problem occurred just recently after making the switch to Xcode 15 + Sonoma + iOS 17 and did not occur with Xcode 14 + Ventura + iOS16.

Let me show you what's bothering me. Look at this simple list.

[image]

Now let's swipe down and reveal a file importer to choose a file and do some stuff (I edited the picture to hide the names of the files). This picture shows the file importer:

[image]

After selecting a file this happens. See the that "progress indicator" thing? I think it's from the refreshable action, however it doesn't disappear. It will stay there indefinitely until you actual start swiping on the list.

[image]

I'm pretty sure this "progress indicator" thing didn't stay there and disappeared when using Xcode 14 + Ventura + iOS16.

Is it just me or does anybody have the same issue with Xcode 15 + Sonoma + iOS 17 ?

Here is the code I used if you want to try it out for yourself.

Here is the ContentView with the list:

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  ProblemDebug
//

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var fileImporterVisible: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text("This is a refreshable list. Swipe down!")
            Text("Let's  see what happens ...")
        }
        // REFRESHABLE
        .refreshable(action: {
            fileImporterVisible.toggle()
        })
        // SHOW SHEET WHEN fileImporterVisible IS TOGGLED
        .sheet(isPresented: $fileImporterVisible, content: {
            ViewFileImporter(fileImporterVisible: $fileImporterVisible)
        })
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

And here is the view with file importer:

```
//
//  ViewFileImporter.swift
//  ProblemDebug
//

import SwiftUI

struct ViewFileImporter: View {
    
    @Binding var fileImporterVisible: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            // DO SOMETHING ...
        }
        .fileImporter(isPresented: $fileImporterVisible, allowedContentTypes: [.plainText, .pdf], onCompletion: { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let spxFileImporterURL):
                if spxFileImporterURL.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() {
                    print(spxFileImporterURL.absoluteString)
                } else {
                    spxFileImporterURL.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
                }
            case .failure(let spxFileImporterError):
                print(spxFileImporterError.localizedDescription)
            }
        })
    }
}

#Preview {
    ViewFileImporter(fileImporterVisible: .constant(false))
}
```

**Update**
It seems like refreshable is working ok on its own. The problem occurs only in conjunction with a sheet.

Does someone have a clue?

```
//
//  ListRefreshable.swift
//  ProblemDebug
//

import SwiftUI

struct ListRefreshable: View {
    
    @State private var showTestView: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
            List {
                Text("A simple, refreshable list")
            }
            .refreshable {
                showTestView.toggle()
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showTestView, onDismiss: {
                showTestView = false
            }, content: {
                EmptyView()
            })
    }
}

#Preview {
    ListRefreshable()
}
```

Comment: I get the same issue.
Using MacOS 14.1, Xcode 15, tested on real ios-17 device (not Previews).
 Updated iPhone to ios-17.1 beta, and still same issue.

Comment: Thank you "workingdog support Ukraine". I can confirm this issue exists on real hardware and simulator.

Comment: File a bug report with apple.

Comment: Thank you. I think at this point this is the only viable option.